# Passing Dynamic Two Dimensional Array as argument to a functoin in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays, pointer-to-pointer

Hy guys, I actually Trying to create a 2D Array in c++ but not able to create that, When I execute the following statement

```
int arr=new int[10][10]
```

It gives me error and when I search on google it shows me 2D array in c++ is array of pointers which is declare like the below statements

```
int** a = new int*[rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    a[i] = new int[colCount];
```

I got the logic which is a is a pointer to pointer to the matrix but now I am not able understand the logic like how can i point to the data on this matrix, Suppose to see the number store in index `a[0][0]` should i write

```
cout<<a[0][0]
```

or not, I am not able to get the logic how this pointer to pointer will work when with the pointers pointing to the matrix, and one more thing is that I am not able to pass it as an argument to a function. The code for passing it as a parameter is given below

```
void displayArray(int a[10][10])
{
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            cout<<*a[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int** a = new int*[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        a[i] = new int[10];

    displayArray(**a);
}
```

It giving me the following error

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int (*)[10]’ [-fpermissive]
```

Actually I am not able to get any sense of how to use the pointer to pointer in a matrix, it's too complex compared to other languages where we just need to use `new` operator and can access them with their dimensions, No need of this pointer to pointer concept. Please help me understanding the whole logic of this 2d dynamic array of c++.

Comment: Pop quiz: what is the type of `a`? That's the same type that the parameter to your `displayArray` must be.

Comment: Question and answers would have more clarity if the sizes where different like `int[10][20]`.  Unfortunate they are the same.

Comment: *I actually Trying to create a 2D Array in c++ but not able to create that* -- [A much better way to do what you are asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: ***"it's too complex compared to other languages"*** - This is not a necessarily a completely fair comparison. Most other languages simply can not so this. It is out of their scope. These are very low level array constructs that even most `C++` programmers never need to use. For something more equivalent to a dynamic array in another language you should look at `std::vector<int>` for an array and `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for a 2D array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the parameter in your function as pointer

```
void displayArray(int **a)
{
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            cout<< a[i][j] <<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int** a = new int*[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        a[i] = new int[10];

    displayArray(a);
}
```

it prints 10 rows and columns of value 0 because the 2D array is uninitialized